# Retrieving text from a P in html using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML structure of below format

```
<p class="question_description">
    question to test autolinker
    <br><br>
    <a class="que_desc_cat_span" href="/category?category=Technology">Technology</a>
</p>
```

I need to extract the text inside the P tag but excluding the text contained inside the Anchor tag.

using .text() function will return whole text; including the text within anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access separate text nodes manually with [**contents()**](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```js
console.log($('p').contents()[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question_description">
  question to test autolinker
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="que_desc_cat_span" href="/category?category=Technology">Technology</a>
</p>
```

Comment: My mistake...Mouse issue :P , clicked the wrong bar

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, that is one feisty mouse! :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE is there a way to set the contents inside the P tag without altering the anchor tags content

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the contents of first child node in `P` so

```js
var text = $('.question_description').contents().first().text();
snippet.log('text from P: ' + text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<p class="question_description">
  question to test autolinker
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="que_desc_cat_span" href="/category?category=Technology">Technology</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

You can use contents, but actually what you want to do is remove all the children tags and then extract the text.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('p').children().remove().end().text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question_description">
  question to test autolinker
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="que_desc_cat_span" href="/category?category=Technology">Technology</a>
</p>

<a href="#">Extract</a>
```

If you'd like the text separately, so you can use it somewhere else, you can `close()` the `p` tag before you remove it's children.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('.question_description').contents().first().text();
console.log(text) // return  question to test autolinker
```